# Is it possible to determine the dataflow within a database?

Tags: t-sql, dataflow

Is it possible to determine the data flow within a database?
e.g. I start by adding/inserting a record in MainTable1, then through a trigger SubTable1, SubTable2 have records inserted into, SubTable3 has a record updated into, then a StoredProcedure1 is run which updates first SubTable4, then a StoredProcedure2 is run which adds a record in SubTable5. So by simply adding a record in MainTable1, I affect 5 other tables.

Imagine a more complex process than this one now (which I'm currently facing and I want to win time and precision; I will still investigate it myself (if I will find an answer first - I will post it here))
Is there a way I could "extract" this flow by using T-SQL?

Comment: SQL 2014 has some built in features that allows tracking of data changes. I don't know anything about it though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb933994.aspx

Here's an article on it for SQL Server 2012. http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/tracking-changes-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler to capture all events that follow insertion. Create and run profile session, initiate insert and see all actions that follows. There are a lot of events that can be captured. For example, SQL:BatchStarting will show your INSERT, SP:StmtStarting shows statements inside of stored procedures etc.

Comment: Indeed, SQL Profiler could show me a flow. But in the scenario where 30 users work against same DB in the same time, using different flows... it would be a night mare (or close) to identify each flow. Or I could initiate myself flows, one by one(using the UI or not), then write down or draw the actual flow. Another issue with this approach could be that it doesn't take in consideration the existing clauses within the SPs or triggers... But, indeed, SQL Profiler could help me in the manual detection. Nevertheless, thank you Alsin for your answer and attention!

Comment: You can filter Profiler traces in different way, to capture only portion of all information. Yep, you can initiate actions one by one and filter by your PID. Main goal of Profiler is to discover that some procedure is called. After that you can review SP to see all clauses.